# Open a file:/// url with #anchor from terminal

Tags: macos, web-browser

I've been trying to open a `file:///` url e.g.

```
open "file:///Users/me/index.html#my-anchor"
```

Or

```
open -a Safari "file:///Users/me/index.html#my-anchor"
```

Or

```
open -a Google\ Chrome "file:///Users/me/index.html#my-anchor"
```

However, the browser location after opening is:

```
file:///Users/me/index.html
```

The hash/anchor has been clobbered.  Is there some way to do this that I'm missing?

(Note: Obviously this isn't what happens with URL's on web servers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A non-specific approach is:

```
 osascript -e 'open location "file:///Users/me/index.html#my-anchor"'
```

Comment: That is what we need!

Comment: Does not work for Chrome unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Safari as default browser either (on macOS 10.14.6). The version where a specific browser is specified does work, however.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use the open command.

**Google Chrome**:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome "file:///Users/me/index.html#my-anchor"
```

**Safari**:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to open location "file:///Users/me/index.html#my-anchor2"'
```

Comment: To be very clear the question is to open the file url via terminal / scripting.  The title is updated.

Comment: I just changes my answer to what you need. Try the above commands in the terminal, I just did and they worked as expected.

Comment: Not sure who else down voted you.  Please remove the initial answer from your post, that was never the intended question.  I will mark as correct when the noise is removed.

Comment: √ Done. What do you need this for?

Comment: Opening downloaded docs from Vim and Emacs and jumping to the relevant item.  Noticed open fails to pass the hash.

Comment: The bigger problem is making this non-specific to a particular browser

Comment: I've switched the correct answer mark to @tharps as it is what is really needed.